# Wrap around subtraction

Tags: r

I have these numbers:

```
login.day$wday
[1] 5 6 7 1 2 3 4
```

and I want to map them to:

```
login.day$wday
[1] 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```

Each number is subtracted by 1, and if the answer is 0, wrap it around back to 7.  This is embarrassingly simple but I just can't figure it out.  My attempt keeps giving me a zero:

```
> (login.day$wday + 6) %% 7
[1] 4 5 6 0 1 2 3
```

Prefer solution in R.  Is it possible to do with modulo arithmetic or must I use an `if statement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically equivalent to the other solution, and with some explanation.

```
(login.day$wday - 1 - 1) %% 7 + 1
```

The problem is that it is hard to do modular arithmetic with numbers starting at `1`.

We start by doing `-1` to shift everything down by `1`, so we have a zero-based numbers ranging from `[0,6]`.

We then subtract `1`, because that is what we were trying to do to begin with.

Next, we take the modulus, and add `1` back to shift everything back up to the range `[1,7]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(login.day$wday + 5) %% 7 + 1
```

perhaps?

The boundary conditions are `7 -> 6`, `1 -> 7` and `2 -> 1`.

The result had to involve `%% 7` as you so rightly spotted.

And since the last of these boundary conditions results in 1, then we need to add 1 after doing the modulo, and reduce the number added before the modulo by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have a silly function I've written called `shift` that does this:

```
shift <- function(x = 1:10, n = 1) {
  if (n == 0) x <- x
  else x <- c(tail(x, -n), head(x, n))
  x
}

x <- c(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4)

shift(x, -1)
# [1] 4 5 6 7 1 2 3

shift(x, -2)
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7 1 2
```

---

The use I had in mind for this was something like the following:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- sample(7, 20, TRUE)
X
#  [1] 2 3 5 7 2 7 7 5 5 1 2 2 5 3 6 4 6 7 3 6

shift(sort(unique(X)), -1)[X]
#  [1] 1 2 4 6 1 6 6 4 4 7 1 1 4 2 5 3 5 6 2 5
```

Comment: `ifelse()` to vectorize the whole thing. I was about to give the same answer.

Comment: @ilir, what's the need for `ifelse`? The `if` here is just to check whether one of the function's arguments is "0". I doubt that `ifelse` is going to give any performance improvement here :-)

Comment: yes you are right. I mistook your code for a simple 'replace-0-for-7' implementation. That's what I usually do and what I was going to suggest, but the pure modular arithmetics answer is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of @merlin2011 but just to add to the options here is a lookup table approach:

```
c(7, 1:6)[login.day$wday]
```